# css3 : remove background from button when dropdown is close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap dropdown with button .
I want to change the background of button as dark gray

```css
button {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7.50px 12px;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  outline:none;
}
button:hover {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
  background: #888888 !important;
}
button:focus {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
  background: #888888 !important;
}
button:active {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
}
button .caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 6px dashed;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="btn-group dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

on hover as well as when dropdown is open. but when I close the dropdown menu then button background would be white.

any help would be great.

thank you.

Comment: As I can see the button is still dark gray when you close as you're hoving over it. It is working fine.
Suggestion: on hover change the background color to lightgray `background: #D3D3D3 !important;` let me know how it works for you

Comment: try not to use !important which will be difficult to update later, use something like this .parentClass button {background: #888; border: 1px solid #cfdadd;}

Comment: @Harman .when i close dropdown then button background should be white.in your answer , i can't see that

Answer (score 2):

Check this. Change red color to any color you want.

Basically you need to use `.open` class

```
.btn-group.dropdown.open button {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.btn-group.dropdown button {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

```css
button {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7.50px 12px;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  outline:none;
}
button:hover {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
  background: #888888 !important;
}
button:focus {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
  background: #888888 !important;
}
button:active {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid !important;
}
button .caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 6px dashed;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 5px;
}

.btn-group.dropdown.open button {
    background-color: red !important;
}

.btn-group.dropdown button {
        background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="btn-group dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: when i close dropdown then button background should be white.in your answer , i can't see that

Answer (score 0):

you can use this js code. Inside the function you change the css property of the dropdown element.

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".my-dropdown").on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(){
  $(this).find("button").addClass("white");
})
```

```css
.my-dropdown button {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7.50px 12px;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  outline:none;
}

.my-dropdown button,
.my-dropdown button:hover,
.my-dropdown button:focus,
.my-dropdown button:active {
  border: thin #cfdadd solid;
  background: #888;
}

.my-dropdown button.white {
  background: #fff;
}

.my-dropdown button .caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 6px dashed;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="my-dropdown btn-group dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: when i close dropdown then button background should be white.in your answer , i can't see that

Comment: @Rishi exactly what you want now, but kind of silly.

Comment: by default the button background would be white and when i click on it and when dropdown is open its background color should be gray and when i click on it again to close the dropdown then its color should be white itself and when i again hover it then its color should be gray again.

Comment: Remove Js and replace my-dropdown button to my-dropdown.open button